# Crystal report unable to refresh data

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I was generating the Crystal Report viewer using WPF and I was able to load data in the report viewer. But when I was trying to create an event to refresh the report dynamically, the data could not be refreshed.

Basically what I have done is creating a dataSet connecting with the MSSQL Server[image]

Then generate a Crystal Report file:[image]

And then trying to import data into the Crystal report viewer in the MainWindow.
Here is the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow: Window
{
   DataSet1TableAdapters.BordierSheetTableAdapter TA = new      DataSet1TableAdapters.BordierSheetTableAdapter();
     ReportDocument reportDoc = new ReportDocument();
  public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Data_Binding();
    }
  public void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
       reportDoc.Refresh();
       crystalReportsViewer1.ViewerCore.RefreshReport();
    }
  void Data_Binding()
     {

         DataSet empDataSet = new DataSet();

         using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
         {
             conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=YATONGHOU\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=messagedb;Integrated Security=True";
             conn.Open();


             string sqlStr = "select * from BordierSheet";
             SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr,conn);

             dataAdapter.Fill(empDataSet, "BordierSheet");
         }

         string reportDataSource = @"C:\\Users\\yatong\\Work\\LogAnalytics\\BordierSheetReport\\BordierSheetReport\\CrystalReport1.rpt";

         reportDoc.Load(reportDataSource);
         reportDoc.SetDataSource(empDataSet);

         this.crystalReportsViewer1.ViewerCore.ReportSource = reportDoc;

     }
}
```

When I updated my data base and then click the button in the window (which triggers the button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) function), no data has been updated.
So could anyone help me with this please?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Where is the code to refresh the report?  What doesn't work?

Comment: It is in the function button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e). And the Refresh method is not working.

Comment: Does it throw an error or simply not refresh?  Have you tried calling Data_Binding before refreshing the report?

Comment: It has "System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element." while debugging. And I think the Data_Binding is indeed executed before refreshing(when the MainWindow initialized).

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
reportDoc.Load(reportDataSource);
reportDoc.SetDataSource(empDataSet);
this.crystalReportsViewer1.ViewerCore.ReportSource = reportDoc;
crystalReportsViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing :

```
reportDoc.Refresh()
```

after doing the data load?

Comment: Isn't it same thing as I did in button2_Click function?

Comment: I would do that at the end of the databinding operation.  CR is finicky like that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this..this is working!

Go to Crystal Report Design > File > Uncheck the Save Data with Report.

That's it then save again.. it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the datasource and add it again , such as:

```
    if ( reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Count > 0)
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.RemoveAt(0);

  reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource()
{
            Name = "ds",
            Value = MyDataSource
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your crystal report data is not refreshed after passing the new dataset to the crystal report setdatasource (`crRpt.SetDataSource(ds)`) method, you are doing a silly mistake.

try instead of above setdatasource (`crRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0])`).

Sample Code

```
crReceipt crRpt = new crReceipt();
string qry = "";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
qry = "SELECT L.LID, L.LName, " +
      "       R.RDate, R.RAmount, R.RRemark " +
      "FROM (Ledger AS L " +
      "LEFT OUTER JOIN Receipt AS R ON L.LID = R.LID) " +
      "WHERE L.LName = 'Pankaj' ";

ds = cn.getDataSet(qry);
crRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);            
crv.ReportSource = crRpt; //crv = crystal report viewer
```